# Flask Login - Multiple kind of Users

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am new to flask, In my project, there are three kind of users[user_a, user_b, user_c] are going to access.

Each users have different operations, but one login page. I used to check the type of user before login and redirect them to corresponding pages.

I created all routes in routes.py file, where user_a can access the user_b's links.

I do not want the user_a access the links for user_b. How to create multiple login managers for three kind of users.

Thanks

Comment: In your User table, how do you differentiate the three user types?

Comment: Could you give us your code please, so we can so what you tried.

Comment: I used to create a column named group in the user table, where I mention the user from user_a or user_b or user_c